# Proving that $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2k+1}{2k \choose k}^{-1}=\frac {2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Mathematica gives away the interesting sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2k+1}{2k \choose k}^{-1}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$
The question is: How to prove it by hand?

**Remark.** This question is self-answered (whence the OP provided an effort).  See the [answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3799521/72152).

Comment: $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^k}{(2 k+1) \binom{2 k}{k}}=\frac{4 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{(4-z) z}}$$

Comment: A simple generalization is a formula due to Ramanujan: $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2 \binom{2 k}{k}}=\frac{1}{3} \left(8 C-\pi  \log \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)$$

Comment: This is wonderful !

Comment: Ramanujam's sum is even more interesting !

Comment: Reverse engeneering Mathematica ? :D

Comment: Someone should prove this (or explain  a bit) Ramanujan thing mentioned by @User628759

Comment: Check this solution by a friend  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3800245/432085

Comment: @Ali Shather Very interesting, in fact, I was already bothering about it in a long way!

Comment: @Paramanand Singh    We have

$$\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1){2n\choose n}}$$

Divide both sides by $2x$ then $\int_0^{1/2}$ we get

    $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2{2n\choose n}}=2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=2\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}d\theta$$

which is well-known

Comment: @AliShather: that's cool! So Ramanujan stuff is not necessarily difficult.

Comment: For that matter even Pythagoras theorem is not difficult !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might help.

$$\frac{1}{n \choose k}=(n+1)\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx.$$
This is easily obtained by integration by parts.

Putting $n=2k$ and $x=\sin^2t$, we get $$\sum_{k\geq0}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\sin^{2k+1}t\cos^{2k+1}t \  dt.$$

Bringing the sum inside the integral and evaluating the G.P. give
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin( 2t)}{1-\frac{\sin^2(2t)}{4}}dt.$$

Putting $\cos(2t)=u$
We get,
$$2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{du}{3+u^2},$$
which is indeed equal to $\dfrac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}$.

Comment: Will use that trick [+1]

Answer (score 5):

Note the integral representation of the reciprocal of the binomial co-efficient:
$${n \choose j}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_{0}^{1} x^j (1-x)^{n-j}~ dx.$$
Then
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{2k+1}{2k \choose k}^{-1}= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} [x(1-x)]^{k}= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-x+1} dx $$ $$ \implies S = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1} \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigg|_{0}^{1}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$