# Proving $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx=\frac{1}{3}(8C-\pi\ln(2+\sqrt{3}))$ for an identity of Srinivasa Ramanujan

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, ramanujan-summation

**Ramanujan is supposed to  have given more than five thousand elegant results, a good number of them are yet to be proved or disproved.**

Yesterday in the comment section of

[Proving that $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2k+1}{2k \choose k}^{-1}=\frac {2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799401/proving-that-sum-k-0-infty-frac12k12k-choose-k-1-frac-2-pi3-s)

A wonderful Ramanujan identity
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}{2k \choose k}^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}(8C-\pi\ln(2+\sqrt{3}))~~~~(1)$$ was showcased, Mathematica also gives this out.

My Attempt to prove (1) by hand:

Note the integral representation of the reciprocal of the binomial co-efficient:
$${n \choose j}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_{0}^{1} x^j (1-x)^{n-j}~ dx~~~~(2)$$
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}{2k \choose k}^{-1}= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{[x(1-x)]^{k}}{(2k+1)} dx= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} dx~~~~(3)$$

The question is:  How to get this integral (3) by hand ?

Comment: **Ramanujan is supposed to have given more than five thousand elegant results, a good number of them are yet to be proved or disproved.** ---- *NO, this is utterly false*. As of 2020, all results Ramanujan had written down *have already* been either proved or disproved.

Comment: @pisco Great to hear this.

Comment: @pisco i firmly disagree, can you provide a trusted source please?

Comment: May I ask OP a question: Are you the discoverer of the so-called "Ahmed Integral"?

Comment: @User 628759 Yes, please.

Comment: Please note  that **Ramanujan** and **Ramanujam** are two different mathematicians. I believe you must mean to be **Srinivasa Ramanujan**.

Comment: Congrats Ahmed I didn't I didnt know that you are the discoverer "Ahmed Integral". Hats off.

Comment: @Ali ShatherThank you very much, I have happened to have made it in 2002.

Comment: I also saw your solution on searchgate its short and elegant. Congrats on such achievement.

Comment: Nice to see a fellow Indian here again!

Comment: @Baba Yaga Let us make a difference.

Comment: @BabaYaga: a lot of mathematicians primarily including Bruce C. Berndt and his collaborators have settled almost all claims of Ramanujan. What is not really achieved so far is the elementary methods of proofs which Ramanujan used. So for most of the difficult results one does not know how Ramanujan proved them.

Comment: @BabaYaga: you should read their books and papers to convince yourself.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh the books are mostly beyond my level but I think I can trust you ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can give Feynman's trick a shot.
\begin{align*}
I&=\int _0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh} \left(\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}}\:dx\\[3mm]
I\left(a\right)&=\int _0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh} \left(a\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}}\:dx\\[3mm]
I'\left(a\right)&=\int _0^1\frac{1}{1-a^2x\left(1-x\right)}\:dx=\frac{4}{a\sqrt{4-a^2}}\arctan \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{4-a^2}}\right)\\[3mm]
\int _0^1I'\left(a\right)da&=4\underbrace{\int _0^1\frac{1}{a\sqrt{4-a^2}}\arctan \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{4-a^2}}\right)\:da}_{t=\frac{a}{\sqrt{4-a^2}}}\\[3mm]
I&=8\underbrace{\int _0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{\arctan \left(t\right)}{4t\sqrt{1+t^2}}\:dt}_{t=\tan\left(x\right)}=2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{6}}\frac{x\sec \left(x\right)}{\tan \left(x\right)}\:dx\\[3mm]
&=2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{6}}\frac{x}{\sin \left(x\right)}\:dx
\end{align*}
That integral has been evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044687/solving-the-integral-int-0-pi-2-log-left-frac2-sin2x2-sin2x-right-m/3044892#3044892) by Zacky, using its result yields
$$\boxed{I=\int _0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh} \left(\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}}\:dx=\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2-\sqrt 3) +\frac{8}{3}G}$$

---

One can also find the last integral by using the Weierstrass substitution.
\begin{align*}
2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{6}}\frac{x}{\sin \left(x\right)}\:dx&=4\underbrace{\int _0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\arctan \left(t\right)}{t}\:\:dt}_{\operatorname{IBP}}\\[3mm]
&=\frac{\pi }{3}\ln \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-4\underbrace{\int _0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\ln \left(t\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt}_{t=\tan\left(x\right)}\\[2mm]
&=\frac{\pi }{3}\ln \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-4\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{12}}\ln \left(\tan \left(x\right)\right)\:dx\\[3mm]
&=\frac{\pi }{3}\ln \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)+8\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2k-1}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{12}}\cos \left(2\left(2k-1\right)x\right)\:dx\\[3mm]
&=\frac{\pi }{3}\ln \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)+4\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\left(2k-1\right)\right)}{\left(2k-1\right)^2}\\[3mm]
&=\frac{\pi }{3}\ln \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)+\frac{8}{3}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{\left(2k-1\right)^2}\\[3mm]
&=\frac{\pi }{3}\ln \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)+\frac{8}{3}G
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Note

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx
\overset{x=\sin^2t} =\int_0^{\pi/2} 2
\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sin 2t}2dt
= \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{\sin2t}2}{1-\frac{\sin2t}2}\right)dt
$

[Solving the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac{2+\sin2x}{2-\sin2x}\right)\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044687/solving-the-integral-int-0-pi-2-log-left-frac2-sin2x2-sin2x-right-m/3044892#3044892) $=\frac{1}{3}[8C-\pi\ln(2+\sqrt{3})]$

Answer (score 3):

If we denote the sum by $S$, we have the short proof

> $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2k}}{\displaystyle (2k+1){2k \choose k}}\textrm{d}x=4\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin(x/2)}{x\sqrt{4-x^2}}\textrm{d}x=2\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\textrm{d}x$$
> $$=4\int_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=4\operatorname{Ti}_2(2-\sqrt{3})=\frac{8}{3}G+\frac{\pi}{3}\log(2-\sqrt{3}).$$
> Q.E.D.

$\operatorname{Ti}_2(2-\sqrt{3})$ is a special value of the inverse tangent integral that is extracted immediately by (**also**) using a famous result by Ramanujan,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2(2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2}=\operatorname{Ti}_2(\tan(x))-x \log(\tan(x)), \ 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2},$$
and these details may be found in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, pages $215$-$216$.

**A note:** To have a clear picture of the arcsine series used one can express $\displaystyle {2k \choose k}$ in terms of $\displaystyle {2k+2 \choose k+1}$ and then reindex the series. That's all.